# How do I manage multiple windows with javafx

Tags: javafx

Im working on an application that is using multiple windows, I have a button with a handle method:

```
private class btnHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                       
        final BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        final URL stylesheet = getClass().getResource("playerStyle.css");
        scene.getStylesheets().add(stylesheet.toString());
        Stage window = new Stage();

        eqButton.disableProperty().bind(window.showingProperty());

        window.getIcons().add(new Image(icon.toString()));
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Title");
        window.show();
    }              
}
```

and it works just fine, but - creates a new window right on top of the first one. So i would like to ask - is there a way to make it appear somewhere else? I want to make it always appear at the side of a first window, regardless of its position - how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make new window (stage) appear at the **right side** of current window (stage) use this

```
newWindow.setX(currentWindow.getX()+currentWindow.getWidth());
newWindow.setY(currentWindow.getY());
newWindow.show();
```

change `+` to `-` to make it appear on **left side**

Comment: Thank you, but your answer brings me to another question - what if I will have to create multiple windows? Do I have to write them all down in one class or can I create a separate class for each of the windows?

Comment: @Nosmer You can do it both ways.If you want to create windows from a separate class then you have to pass a reference of other windows to the class so that new window can be displayed relative to other window